# Windows Phone 7 Mango, handling call events

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

is it possible to intercept incoming calls?
I want to look at the incoming call and see if the number is in the address book and if not I want to make a lookup for the number to one of my services. Is this possible with the Mango update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible. For security and privacy reasons Microsoft doesn't want developers to be able to access SMS and Phone/Call information.